# Можно ли сказать: "Вопрошающее предложение" вместо "Вопросительное"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Собственно, в заголовке я указала свой вопрос. Будет ли словосочетание "Вопрошающее предложение" содержать ошибку?

Answer (score 3):

Так писать не стоит.

"Вопросительное" характеризует тип предложения, отвечая на вопрос "какое?". А "вопрошающее" отвечает на вопрос "что делающее?", что приводит к некоторому олицетворению существительного "предложение". Вопрошающим может быть существо, наделённое речью, интонация/фраза, взгляд. Но предложение не может вопрошать. Оно не совершает действия, не ждёт ответа.

Предложение — это застывшая информация, не способная быть в процессе чего-либо. А многие причастия как раз выражают действия, которые подразумевают процесс, имеющий окончание.  Но "вопрошание" предложения никогда не завершится. Это постоянное состояние, присущее данному предложению постоянно, с момента появления, поэтому у нас не "что делающее?", а "какое?".

Answer (score 1):

> Будет ли словосочетание "Вопрошающее предложение" содержать ошибку?

Думаю, что в самом по себе словосочетании ***вопрошающее предложение*** ошибки нет. Русский язык допускает такое сочетание.

Встречается оно и у известных авторов. К примеру, у [**Якова Гордина**](https://jewish.ru/ru/interviews/articles/175451/)  при разборе стихотворения Бродского [**«Под раскидистым вязом, шепчущим «че-ше-ще»…»**](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&lex1=%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7&parent1=0&mydocsize=971&mysize=213630&max2=1&mysentsize=0&mycorp=JSONeyJkb2NfYXV0aG9yIjogWyLQsdGA0L7QtNGB0LrQuNC5Il19&level2=0&level1=0&ext=10&endyear=1996&mode=poetic&env=alpha&text=lexgramm&min2=1&nodia=1&startyear=1976&parent2=0&docid=MzYxMTc=&sid=p:2_0&expand=full):

> При разборе стихотворения, которое все одно переусложненное
> **вопрошающее предложение**, деепричастие в равной степени можно отнести к двум субъектам действия — шепчущему вязу и раздумывающему
> «я»...

Но как лингвистический термин верно только сочетание *вопросительное предложение* (не *вопрошающее*).